# Set PropertyGrid Default Popup Editor Startup Size (WinForms)

Tags: c#

). How can you set the default size with which the Popup Editor shows up when you invoke it from a Property Grid.

This is for everybody who is familiar with Windows Forms' Property Grid Editor.

You know that if you throw a List property to a Grid, it shows the little [...] button which if you press it pops up its default sub-value editor. I actually use the editor for another type of object, but I gave this example just so you know what I'm referring to. And here's a picture, at least until the link lives:

http://www.perpetuumsoft.de/sf/en/ims/rssSilverlight/GetStart/image032.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that (both for modal and non-modal editors) it is *completely* up to the whim of the control being shown. If the `UITypeEditor` involved chooses a big form, it will be big...

The only way to change that would be to define your own `UITypeEditor` and associate it with the types involved (*sometimes* possible with `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(...)`, that creates the *same* form as the runtime wanted to show, but resizes it before showing.

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for answering. This Property Grid is getting on my nerves. I hate the fact that I need to code something from scratch when all they had to do is provide a little property or even a callback to allow us to customize that default editor a little. Now what frustrates me even more, is, as you can see in the above image, we got that "Add" button, which creates a new instance of whatever object we represent in the popup editor. What kills me is that I don't get a reference to the MAIN object in that constructor (then one from where the modal UI was invoked). Arrrrgh!!!

Comment: Marc, do you have any idea about that other issue? You know... when PropertyGrid objects are created when clicking "Add", they invoke a parameterless constructor on the object in question. How could I get a reference to the original object over there? The ITypeDescriptorContext is of no use ::- (. The "Instance" field points to the Property which is currently edited, and I cannot, by any means, get to the **owner** of that property.

Comment: @Axonn - sorry, I didn't see the comment until just now. No, I don't have a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inheriting from the standard `System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor` and then set the desired size in the `CreateCollectionForm` override.

Decorate your collection to use the custom collection editor.
Below is an example that will start up the collection editor in full screen

```
class FullscreenCollectionEditor : System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor
{
    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        var editor = base.CreateCollectionForm();
        editor.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        return editor; 
    }

    public FullscreenCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

}
```

And then decorate your collection property with `[Editor(typeof(FullscreenCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]` i.e.

```
public class MyModel
{

    [Editor(typeof(FullscreenCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; }

}
```